# erlang thrift cassandra multiget_slice returns empty list

Tags: erlang, cassandra, thrift

I am having issues with multiget_slice cassandra thrift interface in erlang. I am able to get data back from multiget_count for the same set of keys however multiget_slice returns an empty list. I am using thrift 0.8.0 and cassandra 1.0.6. Here is my code

```
Keys = [<<"key1">>, <<"key2">>],
ColumnParent = #columnParent{column_family=ColumnFamily},                                                                                           
SliceRange = #sliceRange{start="", finish="", reversed=false, count=2147483647},
SlicePredicate = #slicePredicate{slice_range=SliceRange, column_names=undefined},

{ok, Conn} = thrift_client_util:new(Host, Port, cassandra_thrift, [{framed, true}]), ok,
{Conn2, {ok, ok}} = thrift_client:call(Conn, set_keyspace, [Keyspace]),
{NewCon, Response} = thrift_client:call(Conn2, multiget_slice, [Keys, ColumnParent, SlicePredicate, 1]),

Response returns the following: {ok, []}
```

However running multiget_count on the same set of keys yield an appropriate result. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to specify some non-empty start and finish in SliceRange.